# Should "merge" only be used when updating the whole entity in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

When trying to update only a few fields of an entity in JPA, should I use merge? Here is what my method looks like:

```
public Entity update(Entity entity)
{
    return entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

For example, I have a person entity with over 10 attributes. I only want to update 2 attributes of the person (their height and gender). Could the entity I pass into this method only contain an ID (the primary key), their new height and new gender with all other fields being null and only update the fields in the database I have given a value for?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are your reasons?

Comment: @Nándor Előd Fekete does it matter why? I'm asking if I'm able to do this and keep all other values in the database the same and not replace them with null?

Comment: It's always a good idea to reveal the problems you're facing because there might be a solution for your problem that might better solve it than the already narrowed solution space you're trying to find your solution within.

Comment: If the rest of the fields are nullable why not?

Comment: Well I've noticed that when I use merge() it replaces the entire entity/row in the database. For example, when I want to update ONLY the username of my user, it tries to replace everything with null including my NOT NULL fields which throws an exception

Comment: Why not just feed in an entity to `merge()` containing the original data except for the fields you wish to change? That's the intended usage pattern, why do you have to differ from that?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete - I disagree, if the entity is already attached, there is no need to use merge for updating values

Comment: @mendieta you disagree with what? a statement of mine? which one?

Comment: This can happen if your `entity` does not have a persistent identity and the ID is auto generated.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete "Why not just feed in an entity to merge() containing the original data except for the fields you wish to change? That's the intended usage pattern, why do you have to differ from that?" If the entity is already attached, I don't think that merge is necessary

Comment: @mendieta that's a special case when the persistence context is active, the entity is attached and a transaction is active, but what does all this have to do with the OP's problem? It's off-topic in my view.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Maybe you are right, but from the comments it looks like merge is the only way to update an entity, just wanted to say it's not.

Comment: @mendieta You are right. The purpose of merge is to sync changes made to a detached entity with the db. But the specification also allows to sync a new entity if passed to it with the database. So it is not illegal.

Comment: The answer is no, you should not pass an incomplete partial entity to merge and expect only the populated fields are looked at.  Merge takes the entire state of what you are passing in and merges it into the managed instance of the entity.  If you only want to change a few fields, create your own method that looks up the entity and modifies only those fields.